# Siunitx without unit macros

Tags: siunitx

The `siunitx` manual states in Ch. 3:

> The unit system can interpret units given as text to be used directly
>   or as macro- based units. In the latter case, different formatting is
>   possible.

To give units directly as text works for simple cases like `\SI{4}{kg}`, but I didn't find any further documentation of how the syntax is parsed if one wants to give units directly as text and not as macros.

For example one might wish that `\SI{4}{m/s^2}` gives the same result as `\SI{4}{\m\per\second\squared}`. Using `\SI{4}{\frac{m}{s^2}}` seems to give the correct result, but I am not sure, if this is a correct way to use it. So is there any further documentation or explanation of how to give units more diretly without using the units macros?

Comment: If you don't want to use the unit macros, the most important rule is that a `.` is used to separate units: `\si{kg.m.s^{-1}}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The is no *parsing* when 'literal' unit input is used. Instead, a small number of substitutions/adjustments are made:

- `.` and `~` represent inter-unit products
- `^` can be used for superscripts
- `_` can be used for subscripts
- Text is printed upright
- Superscripts can be handled using the 'unit' or 'number' font
  setting

With the standard settings, `siunitx` sets units in math mode and so uses `\mathrm`. This will allow `\frac` as it's math mode syntax. If you use `mode = text` then `_` and `^` still work (due to the substitutions) but things like `\frac` will not.

The 'literal' unit mode is essentially the same as that in `sistyle`.

Comment: More or less a re-hash of the manual, page 6 in the current release.